# Need to hover on 5th rating and click on it

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

```
String exePath = "C:\\chromedriver.exe";
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", exePath);
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
//  WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://wallethub.com/profile/test_insurance_company/");
     driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='footer_cta']/span/span")).click();

    // To move to 4th star over the review
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='wh-body-inner']/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div"))).perform();
//  action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='wh-body-inner']/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/a[4]")));
    action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='wh-body-inner']/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/a[5]"))).perform();
    action.click();[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

tried the code but its not hovering neither it is clicking to go to next page

Comment: is navigate to https://wallethub.com/?

Comment: I tried it is navigate to https://wallethub.com/

Comment: it navigates to the  wallethub ,but on the right hand side  of the page review rating stars are there ,i need to hover on the star and need to click on fifth star

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you will need to hover over the ratings section which then exposes a hidden portion of HTML that actually contains the ratings stars, etc. To find the initial element sometimes is hard because when you hover to right-click and Inspect, the element changes. What I usually do is find something nearby to Inspect and then hover the various elements until the right element is highlighted on the page. Another way to find it if it contains text is to search in the HTML for the contained text. Once you find the right element, you just need to hover it and then click on the correct star.

Since I'm assuming you will be using this code repeatedly, I write things like this into a function so that it's easy to reuse.

```
public void setRating(String stars)
{
    // hover over ratings panel to expose ratings stars
    new Actions(driver).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.wh-rating-notes"))).perform();

    // click specified star
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='wh-rating-choices-holder']/a[.='" + stars + "']")).click();
}
```

and then you would call it like

```
setRating("5");
```

I have tested this code and it works.

Comment: This is the complete code... I'm not sure what you are asking.